# How to continue sqlite3_finalize(statement) in for loop. By using below code only one record stored at the end of loop

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

```
-(void)insertIntoDatabase
{

appDelegate =(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


for (int i=0; i < [arrFinalData count]; i++)
{

    countryList =(CountryList *) [arrFinalData objectAtIndex:i];

    insertQuery = "INSERT INTO COUNTRY(NAME,CAPITAL,REGION,SUBREGION,POPULATION,DEMONYM,AREA,GINI,CURRENCIES,CALLINGCODES,BORDERS) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate.database, insertQuery, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while Inserting Data '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate.database));

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        return;
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [countryList.strName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [countryList.strCapital UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [countryList.strRegion UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [countryList.strSubRegion UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [countryList.strPopulation UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [countryList.strDemonym UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 7, [countryList.strArea UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 8, [countryList.strGini UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 9, [countryList.strCurrencies UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 10,[countryList.strCallingCodes UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 11,[countryList.strBorders UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
}

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
{
    NSLog(@"Error while inserting country data in database '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate.database));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"User Inserted Successfully.");
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}

}
```

countryList is my object of CountryList NSObject File in which all string variables declared and value comes from json parsing. Link of json parsing is [this](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all). In this link there are many countries list is available but it stores only one country's detail in SQLite database. So, how to continue store each record one by one in database. 
Thanks!!!!

Comment: Please read the documentation for [sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html).

Comment: <clickety> <click> Or the [SO documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5456/sqlite3-stmt-prepared-statement-c-api/22369/executing-a-prepared-statement-multiple-times) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You must only call `sqlite3_prepare_v2` once, before the loop. Then in the loop you bind all the values, then call `sqlite3_step` to execute the query, then call `sqlite3_reset`. After the loop is when you call `sqlite3_finalize`.

```
- (void)insertIntoDatabase
{
    appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    insertQuery = "INSERT INTO COUNTRY(NAME,CAPITAL,REGION,SUBREGION,POPULATION,DEMONYM,AREA,GINI,CURRENCIES,CALLINGCODES,BORDERS) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate.database, insertQuery, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while Inserting Data '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate.database));

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        return;
    }

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [arrFinalData count]; i++)
    {
        countryList = arrFinalData[i];

        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [countryList.strName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [countryList.strCapital UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [countryList.strRegion UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [countryList.strSubRegion UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [countryList.strPopulation UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [countryList.strDemonym UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 7, [countryList.strArea UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 8, [countryList.strGini UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 9, [countryList.strCurrencies UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 10,[countryList.strCallingCodes UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 11,[countryList.strBorders UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
        {
            NSLog(@"Error while inserting country data in database '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate.database));
            break;
        }

        sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```